# Good style for constructing same object multiple times

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, computer-science

I have to generate three instances of the same object in my code in different places.

```
//This puts ship in new location.
spaceShipLocation location = new PhyiscsEngine();
```

Is it considered bad style to repeat this 3 times in the code or should I wrap it in a method?
(my intuition says no).

p.s
this is for intro to computer science course.

Comment: Do you mean three different instances of the class or do you mean access the same single instance of the class in three different code locations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to instantiate a class, just go ahead and do it. Wrapping every `new Foo()` statement in a method would make your code awful to read and maintain.

Also, since you mentioned 'good style', Java naming conventions state that Class names should begin with a capital letter and use camel case. `spaceShipLocation` (assuming it's a class, due to the code snippet) should actually be `SpaceShipLocation`.

Comment: Agree with @Anthony. Have to say, that in this case (*you need to create simple object 3 times*) calling `new PhyiscsEngine()` is the best approach. Some **Facotry** would be overkill, static factory method isn't needed too. When you don't have to use any setters or you don't pass any different arguments to constructor, you should consider **Sigleton** pattern. But when your objects  are pretty complex but differences between them aren't that big (lets say you have to call ~5 setters, and few of them are mostly the same) you should take a look at **Prototype** patterns and clone your objects

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what you understand by "same":

1. Equal: `a.equals(b)`
2. Identical: `a == b`

You generally have two simple options (among various more complex ones):

1. Equal: Override `PhysicsEngine.equals()` (and `hashCode()` !).
2. Identical: Make `PhysicsEngine` a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), and access the single instance using a static method, such as `PhysicsEngine.getInstance()`. In order to prevent users from creating new instances, you'd make the `PhysicsEngine` constructor `private`

Answer (score 0):

[**Since your question is not clear to me,** i am presenting two solutions from my side]

1)Your instructor wants you to use [Prototype Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern) - **to use existing object to create new one.**

- avoid the inherent cost of creating a new object in the standard way (e.g., using the 'new' keyword) when it is prohibitively expensive for a given application.

2)If you need to have **same instance of an Object throughout the system**. Then [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) is your solution.

- used to implement the mathematical concept of a singleton, by restricting the instantiation of a class to one object. This is useful when exactly one object is needed to coordinate actions across the system.

You will find sample code in the wikipedia articles.

Answer (score 0):

[Effective Java](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc433/joint/EffectiveProgramming.pdf) suggests us to consider Static factories..

```
When there is no need to subclass…
• And one or more of the following
– Significant performance advantage exists
– Need flexibility to return different types
– Can avoid making classes public
– Need control over instances
```

Answer (score 0):

[Singletons Considered Harmful](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?SingletonsAreEvil)

If you find you are "newing up" a class inside another (especially multiple times), it would be better to inject that class' interface.